# Issue with WebADF Application on Windows Server 2008

Tags: arcgis-server

I am trying to resolve this issue with a custom WebADF application that I have migrated from 931 to 10. The appl works fine in Development environment but when deployed on the server, it is throwing an IndexOutOfRangeException. I have traced this error on the server but still don’t see what may be causing this. At this point I am sure that this is an issue with Deafult.aspx. I am not sure if this is related to 32/64 bit in anyway.  Since appl is working fine in development environment, I may be still missing something on the server side.

Appreciate any feedback.

Thanks
jay

Test Environment
Windows XP
Visual Studio 2008

Server environment: 
ArcGIS Server 10
Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard
IIS 7

---

Session State 
Session Key Type Value 
/default.aspx_RefreshUpdatePanel ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.UI.WebControls.RefreshUpdatePanel ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.UI.WebControls.RefreshUpdatePanel 
/default.aspx_RefreshUpdatePanel_ID System.String Toolbar1 
/default.aspxResults$TaskResults1_nodes ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeViewPlusNodeCollection ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeViewPlusNodeCollection 
/default.aspxToc_Panel$Toc1_nodes ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeViewPlusNodeCollection ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeViewPlusNodeCollection 
/default.aspxMapResourceManager1_ValidationTimeOut System.Int32 6000 
/default.aspxMagnifier1_MagMap System.String Map1 
/default.aspxTaskManager1$PrintTask_VBNet1_title System.String Print 
/default.aspxTaskManager1$FeatureSearchTask2_title System.String Feature Search 
/default.aspxTaskManager1$SpatialSearchTask1_title System.String Spatial Search 
/default.aspxTaskManager1$OpenAttributeTableTask1_title System.String Open Attribute Table 
/default.aspxTaskManager1$PostPoints1_title System.String Post User Points 
/default.aspxTaskManager1$GeoprocessingTask1_navigationPath System.String
/default.aspxTaskManager1$GeoprocessingTask1_title System.String Buffer Points 
/default.aspxTaskManager1$GeoprocessingTask2_navigationPath System.String
/default.aspxTaskManager1$GeoprocessingTask2_title System.String Buffer Lines 
**ErrorMessage System.String Page_Error 
Error System.IndexOutOfRangeException System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.    at WebMapApplication.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)    at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)    at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)**

[image]